# Limit navigation in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have a `UIWebView` and I need to intercept all request to check if the website is allowed or not.
For example: the user is surfing on a newspaper page and he press on an Facebook link. The app should block him to reach this page.
Anyone has an idea how to intercept the request?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol in your view controller :

```
@interface MyCustomViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@end
```

and implement the method (in the .m)

`- (BOOL)webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:`

and return `NO` when you don't wan't the web view to access a web ressource (with a test on `request.URL` for example)